# Not using embedded WebKit (OSX App) to perform oAuth2 - possible?

Tags: youtube, oauth-2.0

I would like to move away from using the provided WebKit for oAuth2 in an OSX App. This means that I'm (AFAIK) restricted to only two Redirect URL's:

```
1) http://localhost
2) urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

Being on the mac, I would ideally like to have redirect URL such as myApp://something, but this is rejected by Google as an "invalid URL" for use as redirect.

(2) is not an option as it requires the user to copy/paste a code from the browser. Yik.

I see I can offer a custom port (so I could write/employ a small HTTP server at some port to answer the callback), but is there an easier way (e.g: custom URL scheme above, would be perfect)?

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, I didn't find any alternative to hosting my own in-proc HTTP server to serve requests to "localhost" at a given port. Kinda sucks, but ... meh.